# Associating binary to a Lucene Document

Tags: java, lucene

I have a number of POJO's, each with a String field that I am indexing and searching using Lucene.  However, I seem to be missing an easy way to associate a "found" keyphrase with the (unique) object that it comes from.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't your POJO's have some kind of business key or ID?  Index that along with the String field.